# Error when using using std.compat and iostream in one file

Tags: c++, importerror

I cannot understand why I can't use `std.compat` and `iostream` in one file:

```cpp
import std.compat;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
  char message[] = "world";
  ::printf("Hello, %s!", message);
  std::cout << "Hello, world\r\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error C2668 'std::_Delete_plain_internal': ambiguous call to overloaded function

And if I swap lines with imports, I get other errors:
[image]